# Using JQuery ReplaceWith on input type checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to convert a table with inputs into a table of values. I created this javascript function that works on everything except for input with the type checkbox.

This is my current function :

```
    function PopulateHidden() {

        $('#Units input').replaceWith(function () {
            return this.value;
        });
        $('#Units select').replaceWith(function () {
            return this.value;
        });

        var html = $("#Units").html();
        $('#<%=UnitTableHtml.ClientID%>').val(html);
    }
```

i have tried doing various version of this method:

```
        $(".chk").replaceWith(function () {
            alert(this.html());
            if (this.prop('checked') == true) {
                alert("YES");
                return "Yes";
            };
            return "No";
        });
```

But I keep getting the value of the textboxes as "on" rather than a true/false. I want the value to be Yes or No but it is not getting inside the if statement. Any reason why I cannot get the value of the checkbox as a boolean?

Here is how i defined the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" style="width:20px;height:20px;"/>
```

Comment: Are you getting errors in your console?

Comment: @Jasper No, I am not.

Comment: `this.html()` and `this.prop('checked')` should be throwing errors since `this` is a DOMElement and those methods need to be run on a jQuery object.

Comment: Is there any way around this?

Comment: Create a jQuery object out of `this`...

Comment: Do you want to post the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All praise Jasper as I was building this fiddle with the same suggestion: Needs `$(this)` instead of `this`

http://jsfiddle.net/o8bm0vxx/